# Show that, for every integer $a$ such that $\gcd(a,100)=1$, we have $a^{20}≡1\pmod{100}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Show that, for every integer $a$ such that $\gcd(a,100)\equiv 1$, we have $a^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$.

Based on Euler's theorem, I have $a^{40}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$, but I have problem getting to  $a^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$. And I am wondering if it has to do with the fact that $20\mid 40$?

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: @fleablood I think I have problem figuring out how you get to $a^{20}≡1+50k$ from $a^{4}=1+10k$. My understanding is that $a^{4}=1+10k$, then $a^{20}=(1+10k)^5$. Sorry, I am still struggling here. Can you explain to me where I am wrong?

Comment: The simple way is to try them all.  Make a column in a spreadsheet for each $a$ from $0$ through $99$ and check the ones that are coprime to $10$.

Comment: "The simple way is to try them all."  But for the sake of the question is that fair?

Comment: $a^{20} = (1+10k)^5 = 1 + 5*10k + {5\choose 2}100k^2 + {5\choose 3}1000k^3 + 5*10000k^4 + 100000k^5 \equiv 1 + 50k\pmod {100}$.  Now $a^{40}\equiv 1$ and the only square roots of $1\mod 100$ are $\pm 1$.  And $-1 \not \equiv 1+50k$.

Comment: Ooop $51$ is a square root of $1\mod 100$ (as is $49$) but $51$ is not and even power of element.  I think.

Comment: @fleablood I am wondering if there is a general rule to describe it? Such as $a^{n}≡1 (mod 100)$  is equivalent to $a^{d}≡1 (mod 100)$ if d|n?

Comment: @fleablood Also, wondering how to get to $a^{20}≡1+50k$ to $a^{20}≡1(mod 100)$ Thank you!

Comment: What don't you understand about $a^4 = 1 + 10^k$ so $a^{20} = (1+10k)^5 = 1 + 5*10k + {5\choose 2}100k^2 + {5\choose 3}1000k^3 + 5*10000k^4 + 100000k^5 \equiv 1 + 50k\pmod {100}\equiv 1 + 50k\pmod {100}$?  All the other sumands are multiples of $100$ and are equivalent to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm going to have to write this in an answer. To answer your question about why $a^{20} \equiv 1 + 50k$, expand $(1 + 10k)^5$. It's just$1+5*10k+10*10^2k^2+10*10^3k^3+5*10^4k^4+10^5k^5$. Notice how all the terms after $50k$ are divisible by $100$, so they can be eliminated. From here, the logic in fleablood's comment works.

Comment: Hi, I am wondering if there is a general rule to describe it? Such as $a^{n}≡1 (mod 100)$  is equivalent to $a^{d}≡1 (mod 100)$ if d|n?

Comment: Obvious $a^n\equiv 1 \pmod{100}\not \implies $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod {100}$.  ($11^{40}\equiv 1 \pmod {100}$ but $11^{2}$ or $11^1\not \pmod {100}$).  But $a^d \equiv \pmod{100}\implies a^n = (a^d)^{\frac nd}\equiv 1^{\frac nd}\equiv 1 \pmod{100}$.

Comment: You should 1) be able to follow why $(1 + nk)^m \equiv 1 + (mn)k\pmod{n^2}$ (becase $(1 + nk)^m = 1 + mnk + {m\choose 2}k^2n^2 + ........$). And therefor $(a^4)^5 =(1+10k)^5 \equiv 1 + 50k\pmod {100}$ should be clear. But 2) you should ignore my argument that $a^40 \equiv 1\pmod{100}\implies a^{20}\equiv \pm 1 \pmod {100}$.  I was flat out and out  wrong about that.